# Could not autowire field: Spring-Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, exception

Following is the exception which I am getting while I am trying to integrate Hibernate with my Spring MVC project and add Autowired feature.

**Exception:**

> SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener
>   instance of class
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'userBOImpl': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies fai led; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private com.inspireme.dao.UserDA O
>   com.inspireme.boimpl.UserBOImpl.userDAO; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'userDAOImpl': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationExcep tion: Could not
>   autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory
>   com.inspireme.daoimpl.UserDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is
>   j ava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/hibernate/cache/CacheProvider;

**Dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
 <!-- Enable Annotation based configuration -->
 <context:annotation-config />

 <!-- Base package -->
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.inspireme." />

 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
      </property>
      <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
      </property>
 </bean>

 <!-- Database properties configuration - START -->
 <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" 
    p:location="WEB-INF/classes/properties/database.properties">
 </bean>
 <!-- Database properties configuration - END -->

 <!-- Accessing DB with available credentials - START -->
 <bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
    p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
    p:password="${jdbc.password}">
 </bean>
 <!-- Accessing DB with available credentials - END -->

<!-- Hibernate Settings - START -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
       class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
       <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
       <property name="configLocation">
           <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
       </property>
       <property name="configurationClass">
           <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
       </property>
       <property name="hibernateProperties">
           <props>
               <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
               <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
           </props>
       </property>
   </bean>
<!-- Hibernate Settings - END -->

 <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/inspiremetheme/" />

 <mvc:annotation-driven/>

 <tx:annotation-driven />

 <!-- Start of Autowired beans -->
 <bean id="userBO" class="com.inspireme.boimpl.UserBOImpl"></bean>
 <bean id="userDAO" class="com.inspireme.daoimpl.UserDAOImpl"></bean>
 <!-- End of Autowired beans -->

 <bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <mapping class="com.inspireme.dto.UserDTO"></mapping>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Controller class**

```
package com.inspireme.controller;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class InspireMeController {

    public ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(InspireMeController.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserBO userBO;
```

**Service class:**

```
package com.inspireme.boimpl;

@Service
public class UserBOImpl implements UserBO {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(UserBOImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;
```

**Repository class**

```
package com.inspireme.daoimpl;

@Repository
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

Why am I getting this exception since all the 3 beans, are defined in the dispatcher-servlet.xml file.

I am referring the following [source](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/03/21/spring-3-and-hibernate-integration-tutorial-with-example/) to integrate Hibernate.

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/hibernate/cache/CacheProvider`, jar is missing.

Comment: You are partially correct .. there is a jar mismatch .. as stated here .. http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/12/08/solved-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-lorghibernatecachecacheprovider/.

But after adding this I am getting an error, "WEB-INF/inspireme-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path
esource [hibernate.cfg.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist". Please look at my folder structure and let me know how to give the path here.

Comment: Not exactly sure how the build works in your case but try `classpath:/hibernate/hibernate.cfg.xml` or `classpath:hibernate/hibernate.cfg.xml`. Or better check where exactly that file is within WEB-INF/classes in the deployed war.

Comment: Yep. Worked .. but I got one more exception .. pls give me some time while I check that.

Comment: perfectly working now .. can you please add this as an answer such that I can accept it? 
Also thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Hey, got busy at work. :). But just posted the comments as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/hibernate/cache/CacheProvider` jar is missing.

> You are partially correct .. there is a jar mismatch .. as stated here .. howtodoinjava.com/2013/12/08/…. But after adding this I am getting an error, "WEB-INF/inspireme-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path esource [hibernate.cfg.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist". Please look at my folder structure and let me know how to give the path here.

Not exactly sure how the build works in your case but try `classpath:/hibernate/hibernate.cfg.xml` or `classpath:hibernate/hibernate.cfg.xml`. Or better check where exactly that file is within `WEB-INF/classes` in the deployed war.

Comment: +1 Thanks. I was trying for almost like two hours to solve the issue.